# SQL Server 2012 SSIS - variable expression from execute sql task

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis

SQL Server 2012 SSIS

I have an expression stored in a table column that is retrieved by an execute sql task.

Expression:
"Report Name as of"+" " + Right("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("m",getdate()),2)+"/"+
Right("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("d",getdate()),2) +"/"+
(DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("yyyy",getdate())

I have no problem getting that into a variable, but I want the evaluation of the expression in a variable, not the expression itself.  I've spent about 5 hours today on this.  If anyone has any idea I'd greatly appreciate the knowledge.

Thank you in advance!

Craig

Comment: Do you mean [EvaluateAsExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141663(v=sql.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

set `EvaluateAsExpression=TRUE` in variable property.

Please note -  if you assign an expression to the variable, and EvaluateAsExpression is set to True, you cannot change the variable data type

Comment: Didn't work.  Must be more to it than just setting that property.

Comment: you mean expression is not evaluating. what's value variable getting.

Comment: I get the same string just with added \ marks.  It does not evaluate the expression as an expression.  Do I need to find a way to get it into the expression value for the variable and not the Value value?  Not sure that can even be done.

Comment: \"Adhoc Tracking Report\" +\" as of \"+ Right(\"0\" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart(\"m\",getdate()),2)+\"/\"+\r\nRight(\"0\" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart(\"d\",getdate()),2) +\"/\"+\r\n(DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart(\"yyyy\",getdate())